# Unable to send mail through outlook using Python

Tags: python, winapi, outlook

I am using the below code to send email with an attachment using python. I using the outlook application itselt(not via backend)

```
from time import sleep

import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = "EMAIL ADDRESS"
mail.Subject = "Subject"
mail.HtmlBody = "HTML Body"
mail.Attachments.Add("folderName\\output.zip")
mail.Display(True)
sleep(1)
mail.Send()
```

Its working fine till the line mail.Display(True).  I can see the outlook new mail window open with everything typed in and also file attached. But the next statement mail.send() is giving error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/001.PySelenium/win32email.py", line 16, in <module>
    mail.send()   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\001.PySelenium\venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1) pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467260, 'Operation aborted', None, None)
```

### Debug Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Remove true from display, Why display? you can remove all and just use mail.send()

Comment: Tried that based on the answer given by 'Strive', but didn't work.

Comment: Is pywin32 updated?

Comment: I have latest version 227

Comment: I have added screenshot  on question

Comment: The error code is `0x80004004` (E_ABORT) in hexadecimal. You'll find more solutions when searching for hexadecimal representation of error codes.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `mail.Send()`

By the way, if you want send mail through outlook using Python automatically.

Please comment `mail.Display(True)` and `sleep(1)`, or you cannot send a mail until you manually save changes to the mail.

Please try:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = "my@mail.com"
mail.Subject = "Test"
mail.Body = "Mail"
mail.Attachments.Add("folderName\\output.zip")

mail.Send()
```

Comment: Tried. But didnt work. Commented out mail.Display and sleep and changed to mail.Send(). Still its not sending the mail. Getting same error

Comment: @automaticSoldier it's strange, I have edited my answer, please try another way.

Comment: Tried, but its giving type mismatch error in line     mail_item._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, send_account))

Comment: @automaticSoldier What is your operating environment, WIN10？Python 3?

Comment: Windows 10, Python Interpreter 3.6

Comment: @automaticSoldier My test is successful. I used 3.7, and my outlook version is 2016.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205994/discussion-between-strive-sun-msft-and-automaticsoldier).

Comment: I have related type mismatch error - Can I seek your help please? How did you resolve it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71612438/type-mismatch-in-from-address-of-a-outlook-mailbox-using-python