# Type mismatch in From address of a outlook mailbox using python?

Tags: python, email, winapi, outlook, pywin32

I already referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59618725/python-automated-outlook-email-change-sender-or-default-reply-to-address) and [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192252/python-sending-outlook-email-from-different-address-using-pywin32). Don't mark it as duplicate please.

I have 2 accounts in my outlook application (`user1@org.com` - default profile ,`user2@org.com`)

I 'am trying to send an email message from `user2@org.com` (which is automated email box(department email box) configured in my email box)

When I tried the below

```
for acc in outlook.Session.Accounts:
    print(acc)
```

It prints both email accounts which is `user1@org.com` and `user2@org.com`

However, when I do the below

```
outlook.Session.Accounts[0]
outlook.Session.Accounts[1]
```

It returns the below message

```
<COMObject <unknown>> #but in for loop above, it returns the name of email account
```

So, I finally did the below

```
From = 'user2@org.com' # I manually entered the from address
mail.To = 'test@org.com'
mail.Subject = 'Test Email'
mail.HTMLBody = '<h3>This is HTML Body</h3>'
mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, From)) # this results in error
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) C:\Users\user~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14360/3581612401.py
> in 
> ----> 1 mail.*oleobj*.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, From))
>
> com_error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', None, 1)

How can I properly assign the From account?

**update - smtp email script**

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

sender = 'user2@org.com'
receivers = ['user1@example.com']


port = 25
msg = MIMEText('This is test mail')

msg['Subject'] = 'Test mail'
msg['From'] = 'admin@example.com'
msg['To'] = 'info@example.com'

with smtplib.SMTP('mail-innal.org.com', port) as server:
    
    # server.login('username', 'password')
    server.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
    print("Successfully sent email")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing a COM object, which makes no sense - `print` is probably smart enough to attempt to retrieve the default object property (dispid = 0). If you need a meaningful name, use `Account.DisplayName`.

All you need to do is store the `Account` objct in a variable and assign it to the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property.

Comment: would it be possible for you to write what you suggest as a code (in your answer)?

Comment: Something like `mail.SendUsingAccount = outlook.Session.Accounts[1]`

Comment: Ah I tried this already. Doesn't seem to work for some reason

Comment: What kind of account is it? Also note that all collections in OOM are 1 based, 0, so Accounts[1] will be account #1. Have you tried Accounts[2]?

Comment: Outlook account. I tried 0 and 1 because i only have two acxounts. Typing 2 as index tbrows error

Comment: I understand that it is an Outlook account - Outlook Object Model cannot contain anything but Outlook accounts, right? Is that an Exchange, POP3/SMTP, IMAP4/SMTP, etc. account?
Are you sure you are using Namespace.Accounts collection? Accounts.Item() only allows value 1 through Accounts.Count

Comment: What do you meam by Namesapce above? Sorry, am new to python and outlook automation. Hence, have difficukty understanding your terminologies. If you don't mind, can you write the code that you want me to try amd I will reproduce your code at my system and report the results back? Would really be grateful

Comment: Namespace is the Outlook object returned from Application.Session or Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace

Comment: All accounts are MAPI - Extended MAPI is the native Outlook API.

Answer (score 0):

Manually entered email address is a string type and cannot be assigned as the from account. You need it to be the same object type as the mail item - <class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'>

```
message = 'xyz'
preferred_account = 'user2@org.com'
outlook = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.Subject = subject
mail.Body = message

outlook_acc_to_use = None
for outlook_acc in outlook.Session.Accounts:
    if preferred_account in str(outlook_acc):
        outlook_acc_to_use = outlook_acc
        break

if outlook_acc_to_use != None:
    mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, outlook_acc_to_use))

mail.To = '; '.join(receiver_emails)
mail.Send()
```